# Why am I unable to locate font files(.ttf) in unity android game in persistentDataPath?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, itext, itext7, truetype

Can somebody guide me in the right direction? My android game that I made on unity 2018.4.9 using C# on VS 2017 is unable to detect files at persistent data path.

The two font files are located in the persistent data path directory. [image: This is a screenshot of app persistent data folder.]

This is my code which locates the two font files.

```
    string fontpath1 = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/LEOPALMHINDI15K710.TTF";
    string fontpath2 = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/LEOPALMHINDI14K240.TTF";
    //Check Font 1 existence
    if (File.Exists(fontpath1))
    {
        Debugtext.text += "true1\r\n";
    }
    else if (!File.Exists(fontpath1))
    {

        Debugtext.text += "false1\r\n";


    }

    //Check Font 2 existence
    if (File.Exists(fontpath2))
    {
        Debugtext.text += "true2\r\n";
    }
    else if (!File.Exists(fontpath2))
    {

        Debugtext.text += "false2\r\n";


    }
    //Third File(Image file existence)
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/FullShot.jpg"))
    {
        Debugtext.text += "trueIM\r\n";
    }
    else if (!File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/FullShot.jpg"))
    {

        Debugtext.text += "falseIM\r\n";


    }
    Debugtext.text += Application.persistentDataPath;
```

Debugtext.text is a textbox which shows the result of three files: 
a) Font File 1 
b) Font File 2 
c) An Image File

The debug traces for files 1 and 2 are always false, whereas the image file returns true when it's present.

These fonts files are downloaded using UnityWebRequest from streaming path to persistent path using the following code:

```
    string fontpath1 = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/LEOPALMHINDI15K710.TTF";
    string fontpath2 = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/LEOPALMHINDI14K240.TTF";

    //Request Font1

    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(fontpath1);
    request.SendWebRequest();
    while (!request.isDone)
    {


    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/LEOPALMHINDI15K710.TTF", request.downloadHandler.data);

    //Request Font2

    UnityWebRequest font2 = UnityWebRequest.Get(fontpath2);
    font2.SendWebRequest();
    while (!font2.isDone)
    {


    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/LEOPALMHINDI14K240.TTF", font2.downloadHandler.data);
```

The files are downloaded and written properly to the Persistent data path which is storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.appname.com/files(cross-checked in traces.)

Why are these two font files not being located and returning false while other files in same path returns true?

Please, anyone, help me fix it. I gotta locate these two font files.

Comment: Update: Download is done and webrequest is disposed. It is now returning true for both files existence. But pdf is not registering them still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

Allways use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) instead of hardcoding system paths via string concatenation `+ "/"`! `Path.Combine` rather uses the correct path separators according to the running OS

```
string fontpath1 = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "LEOPALMHINDI15K710.TTF");
string fontpath2 = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "LEOPALMHINDI14K240.TTF");
```

---

Then note that you check for existence of the fonts in the **`streamingAssetsPath`** while for the image you check in the `persitentDataPath` ...

So to answer the question

> Why  are these two font files not being located and returning false while other files in same path returns true?

You are not looking in the same path!

You probably wanted to check the existence for the fonts also in the `persitentDataPath`.

Afaik direct `System.IO` don't work for the `streamingAssetsPath` on Android since it is packed. That's why you are using `UnityWebRequest` to read them. So for `streamingAssetsPath` these checks will probably always be `false`.

Comment: Update: Download is done and webrequest is disposed. It is now returning true for both files existence. But pdf is not registering them still.

Comment: I will update the pdf registering codes as soon as I reach office.

Comment: Your question wasn't about anything regarding PDF. It was why `false` is returned when you check for the existence of the two font files ...

Comment: The whole point reading fonts in persistent data path is to register it using PdfFontFactory for localization of the pdf that my game generates. 

Instead of reading directly from streaming assets path app is downloading fonts fro streamingAssets to PersistentDatPath using UnityWebRequest. It return true for file's existence now but Pdf should register them as well which is not the case. I thought pdf is not registering the fonts because existence is not returning true, but it returns true for both files now. Do you want me to create another question to ask that?

Comment: @DivyanshuAgarwal yes that would be the way to go ;)

Comment: on it. @derHugo. In 5 minutes my post will be submitted. Pleae help me fixing this issue. I am posting error logs as well that occurs when I save the pdf with my local language fonts after I downloaded those from streaming paths to persistent data path using unityWebRequest and returning true for its existence in the persistent data path.(It returns true). I am using System.IO.Combine method.